# Flattening elements doesn't yield aligned elements

Tags: css

Could someone please point out why the following doesn't yield three lines that begin at the same point? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AfzeL/1/) is what I mean.

```
<style>
p,table,td,tr,tbody { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: solid 0 }
</style>
<p>Nothing to write home about</p>
<table><tr><td>Nothing to write home about</td></tr></table>
<p>Nothing to write home about</p>
```

I have explicitly "flattened" all the elements I'm using, haven't I?

Comment: Thanks for all the prompt replies. I guess border-spacing looks like the most natural property to adjust in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have residual spacing on the table elements. Add `border-spacing: 0px` and it'll remove the extra padding from the table cell.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfzeL/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You have extra padding in the border of the table cells. There are many ways to fix this. One is to set the cellspacing to 0:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfzeL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
```